# get_headers is unreliable in this case. Any way around it?

Tags: php, mysql, http-headers

I am using the following to check if a page exists.

```
for($i = 620; $i <= 630; $i++) 
{
    $url = 'http://fantasy.mlssoccer.com/web/api/elements/'.$i.'/';
    $headers = @get_headers($url);  
    echo $headers[0].'<br>';
}
```

Sometimes this give 10 `HTTP/1.1 200 OK` and other times the last 5 are `HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error`

Is there any way around this? If you visit the pages after 625 and refresh, you'll get a page saying `500 Internal Server Error nginx` or sometimes you'll get a page starting with `Piston/0.2.2 (Django 1.4.4) crash report:`.

Any idea how I can check if a (valid non-crash) page exists with this happening?

Comment: `get_headers` is not unreliable, the website you are hitting is.

Comment: I just tried going to the above site with i=625 and got the 500 error. Seems to be a problem on the server side.

Comment: @jordanm Bad choice of wording, but you knew what I meant. I can't trust it to work as-is.

Comment: its not problem in your code, its problem in this website `http://fantasy.mlssoccer.com/web/api/elements/625/`.

Comment: @Floris I know that. What I am looking for is how to check if an URL exists when the target server does this.

Comment: @YogeshSuthar That doesn't help me though. I know the server is giving random 500's or 200's for this number, but for valid URLs, it will ALWAYS work fine. I am looking to get my script to tell me when it's a  500 page OR a crash page. This way I can program it to accept only valid URLs.

Comment: Define "if a URL exists". You are able to form it - so in that sense it exists - but the server doesn't provide a valid response. I think that means "at this moment the server cannot locate the resource requested with your Uniform Resource Locator". I would call that "the URL doesn't exist".

Comment: Are ou saying there are some URLs that will sometimes give the `200 OK` response, and at other times the `500` response? There is no cure for that as far as I can see...

Comment: @Floris Ok, maybe my wording is bad, but it looks like you are intentionally avoiding what I'm asking. I am trying to get it to recognise the 3 scenarios... Working page, 500 page, OR crash message.

Comment: I suggest you use `get_headers()` to grab the site's headers and test if the HTTP status code is acceptable (`200` is `OK`, `301` for permanently moved, there's a whole list on wikipedia). If the server has an issue it can't resolve, it sends a `500` status; `401` says that resource doesn't exist. Oh wait, you already figured that out. What's the question?

Comment: @Floris If you check pages 1 to 624, they will ALWAYS work. There are new ones added every couple of days. The problem is with the pages that don't have anything there yet.... they will give 500 or the crash message instead. I want my code to only work on valid pages, not 500's or crash messages. Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: Cully - I am not "deliberately avoiding" - I'm trying to point out that your question is vague - the idea of these comment threads is to help clarify it. It seems that as this thread evolves, your question is becoming clearer so it's working.

Comment: @JaredFarrish My question is clear above. It looks like I need to re-word it because people aren't reading it properly.

Comment: @Floris My question is very simple really. Does a valid page exist? Yes or no? I don't want it to count crash pages as valid, but it does.

Comment: [HTTP spec.](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt) I think you're over-thinking it or just don't understand what you have in your hands already. When you get the headers with that function, what is in the zero-index *is* what you're after; the *status* of the resource. If it's `500`, *it's inaccessible by server misconfiguration or unrecoverable error*. `HTTP/1.1 200 OK` is *what you want*. Read on, others *maybe* (`301` should have a redirect in the headers). So parse out what the status is from that index you're printing and use that to determine whether the page is suitably available or not.

Comment: I have summarized what various people have said in the answer below, which will print out that a page exists if a "200 OK" answer is returned, and for any other response will say that it does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Summarizing what was said by various people into a standalone php script (this works from the command line - I'm sure you can make it work inside a web page):

```
<?php
for($i = 620; $i <= 630; $i++)
{
    $url = 'http://fantasy.mlssoccer.com/web/api/elements/'.$i.'/';
    $headers = @get_headers($url);
    $match = preg_grep("/200 OK/", $headers);
    if (strlen($match[0]) == 0) {
      echo "page ".$i." does not exist!\n";
    }
    else {
      echo "page ".$i." exists!\n";
    }
}
?>
```

This produced the following output just now:

```
floris$ php valid.php 
page 620 exists!
page 621 exists!
page 622 exists!
page 623 exists!
page 624 exists!
page 625 does not exist!
page 626 does not exist!
page 627 does not exist!
page 628 does not exist!
page 629 does not exist!
page 630 does not exist!
```

Comment: A simple `strpos()` for the test would do.

Comment: Thank @JaredFarrish - I flit between so many languages that I frequently overlook the obvious.

Comment: @Floris Thank you so much for this and sorry for getting a bit ratty before. This problem was frustrating me and it's late so I'm a bit cranky. Seems to work perfectly.

Comment: No worries - everybody needs to take a pill from time to time... glad we got this sorted. Big shoutout to Jared, too!